# File exists, but open file still always returns -1

Tags: c++

File "~/workspace/Test.txt" does exist, but fd always returns -1. Can somebody please give a hint as to what is wrong with the code? Thanks.

```
 int fd = open("~/workspace/Test.txt", O_RDONLY);
 cout << "fd is "<<fd<<endl;
 if (fd < 0) {
    cout << "did not find file"<<endl;
    return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Assuming your OS is some Posix like Linux)

The `~` should be expanded. Usually the shell expands it. But `open` wants a real file path.

You could try:

```
std::string fname (getenv("HOME"));
fname += "/workspace/Test.txt";
int fd = open(fname.c_str(), O_RDONLY);
if (fd<0) {
   std::cerr << "failed to open " << fname 
             << " : " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
   return false;
}
```

See [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html), [wordexp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html), [getenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html), [strerror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html), [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html)

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Comment: Which doesn't mean `open()` does so in turn.