# mkdir() directory created but not found

Tags: java, directory, mkdir

Using Eclipse 4.4.1 and ubuntu 14.04
the code is simple

```
static File PATH = new File ("~/Folder");
PATH.mkdir();
```

It prints out true on the first run and false on the subsequent runs which makes sense since the folder would be created, but I've checked the directory manually and its not found in  ~/ .
I suspect the code makes the directory somewhere I didn't expect. but how can I make it in the home directory of the user. so I can use ls and see the folder.

Comment: Probably the same issue as  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28260681/841108)

Comment: Have you searched to find out where the folder has been created?